# os.path modulo python

Tags: python

Alguém pode me explicar o que ocorre nestas 2 linhas?

```
caminhos = [os.path.join(pasta, nome) for nome in os.listdir(pasta)]
arquivos = [arq for arq in caminhos if os.path.isfile(arq)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse código usa o conceito de `list comprehension`.
`List comprehension` é um açúcar sintático da linguagem python que segue a seguinte notação:

```
  [expressão for item in list if condição]
```

O que ele faz é: para cada *item* do iterável *list* caso *condição* for verdadeira ele executa *expressão* e armazena o resultado numa variável que é uma lista (os colchetes).

Dessa forma, na primeira linha do código todos os nomes (arquivos e subpastas) dentro da *pasta* são concatenados com o path gerando o caminho absoluto.
A segunda linha apenas verifica qual desses *paths* são arquivos (note que podem haver subpastas).

Comment: entendi, mas porque os parâmetros pasta e nome? ele não deveria concatenar os dois?

Comment: ```pasta = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\mp3' 
caminhos = [os.path.join(pasta, nome) for nome in os.listdir(pasta)]
arquivos = [arq for arq in caminhos if os.path.isfile(arq)]
mp3 = [arq for arq in arquivos if arq.lower().endswith(".mp3")]```

Comment: *Nome* e *pasta* foi apenas para seguir sua nomenclatura. Seguindo seu comentário pasta = `C:\Users\user\Desktop\mp3`

Answer (score 1):

Como `os.listdir()` retorna o conteúdo da pasta nome por nome, sem o caminho, o autor usou `os.path.join()` para criar strings com o caminho completo.

`os.path.join()` junta dois ou mais pedaços de um caminho de arquivo. É *quase* o mesmo que concatenar, mas tem algumas diferenças:

- Se o nome da pasta não terminar em barra, ele coloca a barra certa automaticamente, dependendo do sistema operacional (`/` no linux e `\` no windows);
- Se um dos nomes passados como parâmetro começar com uma barra, significa que é a partir da raiz, então as pastas anteriores a esta são ignoradas.

A segunda linha usa `os.path.isfile()` para filtrar somente os caminhos que sejam **arquivos**, ignorando portanto subpastas e outros ítens especiais que possam estar dentro da pasta.

Comment: entendi, muito obrigado.